# Why when I enclose my StreamWriter/StreamReader/NetworkStream in an using statement my server crashes c#

Tags: c#, networking

I have the following statements in my networking server:

```
 using(NetworkStream networkStream = client.tcp.GetStream());
     {
            if (networkStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                 using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream, true))
                 {                      
                    //do something   
                 }
            }
     }
```

The problem is that when I use the using() block like in this case (or with StreamWriter) I get the following exception:

> an established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine

Without the "using" it works great but I thought it was a good practice to call "using" on IDisposable classes.

**EDIT**: Stepping throw the debugger saw that it crashes in this part:

```
 using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(c.tcp.GetStream()))
 {
        await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(data);
        await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
 }
```

But all the data in the variables are correct, no null StreamWriter and the data has values.

Comment: I think we need more info. Step through code in debugger. All I can think of is that a StreamReader dispose will also take with it, the underlying stream.

Comment: @BenHall Sure, what kind of info can I provide to expand the problem? I dont know about taking the underlaying stream because that would give a "ObjectDisposedException" instead of the one that i got if im not mistaken.

Comment: Yer indeed. Have you stepped through. Where exactly does it blow up?

Comment: @BenHall I did an edit with somethings that i found while debugging

Answer (score 0):

I think it is closing the connection too early and you need to read the response from the server after your write.

Try as a crude test for this after your write:

```
do
{
   await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
} while (networkStream.DataAvailable);
```

You'll need to add another `using` for the `StreamReader` above the one you have for `StreamWriter`.

So something like:

```
using (NetworkStream networkStream = client.GetStream())
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
{
    await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(data);
    await streamWriter.FlushAsync();

     do
     {
         await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
     } while (networkStream.DataAvailable);

     networkStream.Close();
}
```